# How to take to nibbles from a byte of data that are chars into two bytes stored in another variable in order to unmask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have two uint_16ts that I've gotten from the nibbles of my data as seen in the code below. I need to put that into mask set so that each of the nibbles are now in its own byte. The code I got is below I can't for the life of me figure it out. I need to do this cause this will create the mask I will use to unmask mildly encrypted data.

```
uint16_t length = *(offset+start) - 3;
uint16_t mask = length;
if(Fmt == ENCRYPTED) {
    char frstDig = (length & 0x000F)
    char scndDig = (length & 0x00F0) >> 4;
    mask =
```

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying. "I have two uint_16ts that ..." I dont see **two** uint16_t. Did you mean "two chars" ?

Comment: If what you are asking is "Is there a value for `mask` that will reverse what I did with the two `&` and `&` & `>>` operations?", then no, there isn't because the reverse would depend on the same expressions applied in reverse and the value of each expression will depend on the value at hand, not just what bits are involved. That prevents a single `mask` from working to undo what was done.

Comment: Edit there was an error i meant two chars cause i has to be able to store letters. I'm not trying to reverse something I did. This is something I have to calculate in order to use undo something that's been encrypted by being XORed by the proper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift one of the digits by 8 bits, and OR them together.

```
mask = (scndDig << 8) | frstDig;
```